# Код для бана библиотека discord.py

Tags: discord.py

Хочу узнать код для блокировки участнкика в дискорде. библиотека discord.py
потратил весь день, не смог найти

Comment: Здесь принято обращаться за помощью, а не за готовым кодом. За готовым кодом обращайтесь к фрилансерам за деньги, либо к chatgpt: https://imgur.com/a/SeK6qyy

Answer (score 0):

```py
member.ban(reason="BAN")
```

не?